# How to create a Web Service client and parse the results in MQL4?

Tags: mql4

I am starting to develop my EA using MQL4 and I would like to consume an WebServices API avoiding to use an external Library (DLL) but would like to construct in MQL code. Is there anyone experienced with this who could help?

Comment: Yes, EAs are allowed to communicate with trusted URLs with native `WebRequest` function. so, you can call Rest API easily.

Comment: Would you have a code example for that?

Comment: Open your MetaEditor.exe and type `WebRequest` then press F1 to read about it.